# Why is Microsoft selling physical media games for Series S?

Tags: hardware, digital-distribution, xbox-series-x-series-s, physical-media

I am confused as to why the following products exist:

[image: Just Dance 2021]
[image: Flight Simulator standard edition]

Why is Microsoft selling physical media games for Series S when there is no disc drive on Xbox Series S?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why Microsoft is selling physical media games for Series S

They're not. If you look more closely at the box art, you'll notice that these games are for Series X. There is no mention of "Series S" at all.

Microsoft Flight Simulator only mentions Series X (also notice the Series X logo in the upper right corner):

[image: Microsoft Flight Simulator box art]


Just Dance even mentions the old Xbox One, but still no Series S:

[image: Just Dance 2021 box art]


You are confused because the shop you've visited (which I presume is [digitec.ch](https://www.digitec.ch)) didn't properly label those products. They might not know about the Series S' lack of disc drive, or they didn't think about it when they created the labels.

---

For the reference, here's what the Series X|S logo looks like on the Microsoft Flight Simulator store page on [xbox.com](https://www.xbox.com/en-us/games/microsoft-flight-simulator) (note that this is an official Microsoft store which only sells games digitally):

[image: Series X|S logo]

Comment: @Josefine I dont even think flight simulator has a physical version except for a limited run made for PC only, which has 10 disc's, according to Wikipedia.